# ReactJs: How to pass api data to components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios

I call api in Home.js file with componentdidmount in class component and i want to render this data in child components with functional components.when i call api in every each child component, its work but when i try to call with props coming only empty array by console.log please help.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import '../styles/home.css'
import axios from 'axios';
import Teaser from './Teaser'
import Second from './Second'
import Opening from './Opening'
import Menu from './Menu'


export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get("https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_url,permalink,username&access_token=IG")
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ posts });

      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
       <Teaser/>
       <Second/>
       <Opening/>
       <Menu posts = {this.state.posts}/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'

import axios from 'axios';

function Menu(props) {

    const {posts} = props;
    console.log(props);


    return (
        <>
        {posts && posts.map(
          (post) =>
            post.caption.includes('#apegustosa_menu') &&
            post.children.data.map((x) => (
              <div className="menu_item" key={x.id}>
                <img className="menu_img" src={x.media_url} alt="image" />
              </div>
            )),
        )}
      </>

    )
}

export default Menu
```

Comment: In the home component can you share what is console.log(this.state.posts) ?

Comment: after console.log(this.state.posts) i get 3 array object but one of them is empty @Harry

Comment: will this api ```https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_url,permalink,username&access_token=IG``` work if i fire from my side ?

Comment: no! i deleted the Access token part cause of security :(

Comment: No worries, in the Menu component can you try console.log(props.posts) ?

Comment: Sure! i did and same result :( i get one empty and 2 filled array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242829/discussion-between-harry-and-hilmi).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
  return (
    <>
      {
        posts && posts.map(post => (
          post.caption.includes("#apegustosa_menu") && post.children.data.map(x => {
            return <img src={x.media_url} alt="img"></img>
          })
        ))
      }
    </>
  )
```